# VisibilityOfElementLocated is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[`visibilityOfElementLocated()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) method in selenium is not working well, sometimes this method passes true, and after that when i trying to fetch element by [`findElement()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is gives error is element is not visible. Following is the code.

```
waitPath.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Table1")));
WebElement we1 = pathfinderdriver.findElement(By.id("Table1"));
waitPath.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Table3")));
```

Even i have checked with following code but sometimes it also fails.

```
while(!(we1.findElement(By.id("Table3")).isDisplayed() ))            
{          
 Thread.sleep(3000);
}
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement we2 = we1.findElement(By.id("Table3"));
```

Comment: Could you show us the error message from the code in the 1st block? Your code in the 2nd block will throw `NoSuchElementException`  at `while(!(we1.findElement(By.id("Table3"))` if the element does not exist.

Comment: Error is -                 Table3org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == Table3 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Can you share the html code for the same??

Comment: It quite weird. Basically, the Wait will throw TimeoutException instead of NoSuchElementException.  Are you sure that the error message is from `waitPath.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Table3")));`

Comment: </SCRIPT>
 <INPUT id=__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED type=hidden name=__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED> <INPUT id=__EVENTVALIDATION value=0h5mDxCkthNzQYAr+l+0L1WYPLBHyGt0CRgsLID07l8OnWCe+7ThBmASIkEVqhsKgAMt0E/fV3owj8hFhUJRKZtY83M= type=hidden name=__EVENTVALIDATION> 
<TABLE style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 102%; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" id=Table1 border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TABLE id=Table2 border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" align=left>
<TD>
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%" id=Table3 border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD bgColor=#ffcc66 vAlign=top width=160>

Comment: No wait is not throwing the error, after wait find element throwing

Comment: Could you show me the code that you create the `waitPath`?

Comment: waitPath = new WebDriverWait(pathfinderdriver, 30);

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: Sure. However, I'm still confused. Regarding your code in 1st block, the first statement and the last statement are wait.until, which will throw a TimeoutException. You said that the `pathfinderdriver.findElement(By.id("Table1"));` is the one that thows NoSuchElementException. But the error said `Unable to find element with id == Table3`. Could you clarify this? By the way, you have to mention my name so I can see your comment in my inbox.

Comment: Hello Bhuban, I was faceing issue with findelement() so i applied wait.until but sometimes it passes wait.until (means element is visible) but in findelemrnt() it gives error. So i do not know how much time to wait. I applied thread.sleep() also, but it also fails sometimes

Comment: Is there anyone who will help me out??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another method like **xpath** to get the element.

```
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By)
```

Comment: ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("..."))